# How would I implement an OnClick Listener for a WebView Class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener, android-videoview

I'm trying to implement an OnClick event for a class in WebView that opens androids internal video player when the OnClick is triggered. Additionally it needs to get the video that is going to be played and play it in Androids video player. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview?authuser=1#BindingJavaScript).

```kotlin
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //...
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(MyJavascriptInterface(this), "Android")
    }

    class MyJavascriptInterface(private val context: Context) {
        @JavascriptInterface
        fun showVideoPlayer(url: String) {
            // TODO: show video player using url.
        }
    }
}
```

And then, call JavascriptInterface function on javascript side.

```html
<script>
    function showAndroidVideoPlayer(url) {
        Android.showVideoPlayer(url);
    }
</script>

<button onClick="showAndroidVideoPlayer('https://example.com')">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Looks good but how would I account for a video that has a different URL?

Comment: @jono1234 I didn't understand what `account for a video that has a different URL?` means. Could you add more detailed explanation and html, javascript code?

Comment: My website has an in-built video player, however i want to override that in an app using webview. The class that is used (mat-button-wrapper) is the same for all videos. I want to have a OnClick listener for that specific class so when its clicked it directs a user to androids internal video player and plays the video that would have been played on the websites internal player. Hope this clears everything up